# How to get the image file path from mySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows

I am retrieving the image and other information to to users with the following code. I would like to also get the image file path display in a textbox below the image. I have been trying to do that without success.

The following is the code which I have written, I have other matters work out except getting the image location from mysql display.

Please anyone help me with his!

```
private void showData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string myConnection = "datasource = localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=root";
                string Query = "select * from MawkMo.Enlist_info;";
                MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
                MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, sqlConnection);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                try
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    myReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {

    byte[] imgbyte = (byte[])(myReader["Photo"]);
                            if (imgbyte == null)
                            {
                                PhotoBox.Image = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //string imgPath = (string)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                                //Photo_path.Text = imgPath;
                                MemoryStream mryStream = new MemoryStream(imgbyte);
                                PhotoBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mryStream);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: why are you storing image as BLOB. Its not a good option. Browsers can't cache the file. Always store image on server and then you can store file location in database.

Comment: @WYSIWYG This doesn't look like a web application to me...

Comment: There doesn't appear to *be* a "path" for the image as it's stored directly in the database. Do you have a column in `MawkMo.Enlist_info` that stores that path name?

Comment: It's not a web application. It's windows forms application.

Comment: @Ic I have a column called Photo which store the image as BLOG DateType.

Answer (score 1):

In the code's current form, you cannot retrieve an image file path because you aren't actually storing the image as a file, you are storing it as a series of bytes in the database.  You won't find image files on the server's hard drive anywhere, and the images won't be retrievable outside your application.

If having access to the images independent of your application is a concern, or if you don't want the image stored in the database (performance concerns) then you would need to re-design the database.  In your database saves you would issue the `Image.Save()` method to save the file to a specific location, and then store that string (ImageLocation) into the database rather than storing the image itself as a byte array.  The retrieval process is then simply to retrieve the ImageLocation String and use it in the `Image.FromFile()` method.

Answer (score 0):

What is a  `PhotoBox.Image` is?

```
MemoryStream imagebuf=new MemoryStream((byte[])myReader["Photo"]);

//create image object
System.Drawing.Image outImage=System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imagebuf,true);
outImage.Save(Server.MapPath(“PhotoTemp/”)+”2.gif”);
```

Comment: PhotoBox.Image is the box where image will be displayed if there is an image.

Comment: the system doesn't recognize this "Server.MapPath(“PhotoTemp/”)+”2.gif”"